# Microsoft Blend for Visual Studio jumps out of the DataTemplate editing state on running the application

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, blend

Right-click on the ListBox
select **edit additional templates**
select **edit generated items (ItemTemplate)**
select **edit current**
(**Objects and Timeline** window now focuses on the **DataTemplate** of the ListBox)
I do my edit
Run the project (run from visual studio or blend no difference in this case)
Stop the run
Now I'm again on blend but **Objects and Timeline** window shows my root container(grid for me) instead of **DataTemplate**!
What's the problem here?
I've tried everything like save before run, keep items selected, launch blend separately, ... nothing solved the problem and still have to go to the **DataTemplate** editing focus after each time I run the project.

Comment: There has been a raft of questions about problems with all the Visual Studio tools on here lately making me wonder about the quality of these things.

Comment: Almost 5 years ago on expression blend had the same problem and still not solved. Sometimes it keeps focus on DataTemplate editing but most of the time blend jumps out of it and again should go through the selections.